# Localization in Silverlight, need multiple binding in XAML

Tags: xaml, binding, silverlight-4.0, localization

We're trying to do some localization in our Silverlight app. Normal localization is no problem: we write the bindings in XAML and our textblock items show the correct text.

For items in datatemplates or for enums, we are experiencing some issues. We are binding a property (string) to the content of a button in the datatemplate. We have our 7 values shown on 7 buttons. But now we try to get those values from the dictionary (resx) and we cannot get a decent binding working. This is how we try now:

```
Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ApplicationResources}, Path=?}"
```

At the question mark is where we used to place our static key: ItemType. But now we need to get the value from a collection bound to the parent (listbox) of the button.

Is there any syntax that can make this binding work?

We also doing something similar with enums binding to comboboxes. Any ideas on how we can get that localization to work?

Thanks in advance